# Why does Input trigger on first click (only)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

see this [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bj0bay3w/)

`$('input:text').trigger('input');`

I need to trigger input change when input is change programatically and not with events(keypress,input change).
On my fiddle the input changes only when I clicked a table row at second time.

For example,

1)click the button beside the apple

2) click the first row(A1,A2,A3).

This will not detect that the "Apple" input has changed,
but if  I try to click the button beside Banana or cherry, this will now detect changes for the Banana or Cherry input field.

Answer (score 0):

You were correct about using the `trigger` function.

Add it here:

```
$(clickedButton).parent().prev().find('input').val(tds.eq(0).html());
```

Like this:

```
$(clickedButton).parent().prev().find('input').val(tds.eq(0).html()).trigger("input");
```

Also, note that this code:

```
$("#table1 >* input").each(function() { /**/ }
```

in your fiddle is placed *outside* of `$(document).ready()` - move it into the `$(document).ready()`, otherwise you're calling it on uncomplete DOM, it causes issues as well.

Comment: It does. You have problems with `oldVal` - it is `undefined` after initialization. Then in function `foo` you are searching for input elements with value set to `undefined`. That's why it fails in the beginning. Use a debugger of `console.log()` to trace these values.